# Menu view for several layouts

Tags: java, android, layout, view

I've created a layout with a menu view that will be in other layouts showing some buttons. To define these buttons and their actions, I'm creating an independet class to define all of them and this way I avoid to have to define all of them again and again in all the activities.

To do this, first I've created the menu_view layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <!-- Button columns -->
    <RelativeLayout   
        android:id="@+id/border_left"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#000000" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="launch_radio"
            android:src="@drawable/radio_button" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/musicButton"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="launch_media"
            android:src="@drawable/music_button" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

NOTE: Here aren't all the buttons, I only put 2 to have an idea.

After this, I created the MenuView class where I define all these buttons and what they do:

```
public class MenuView extends RelativeLayout {

private final LayoutInflater inflater;

public MenuView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_view, this, true);

    ((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.navButton)).setOnClickListener(launch_nav);
    ((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.phoneButton)).setOnClickListener(launch_phone);
    ((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.webButton)).setOnClickListener(launch_web);
    ((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.backButton)).setOnClickListener(goBack);
}

 private final OnClickListener launch_nav = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Navigation.class));
    }
};

**¡¡¡THROUBLE!!!**
private final OnClickListener launch_phone = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        public void launch_phone (String number) {
            String numberToDial = "tel:"+number;
        }
        getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(numberToDial)));
    }
};

private final OnClickListener launch_web = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getContext().startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.es")));
    }
};

**¡¡¡THROUBLE!!!**
private final OnClickListener goBack = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), NO.class));
    }
};
}
```

Here is where I'm a little bit lost. I have to define 2 actions:

1- The phone dialer
  2- The goBack key

The phone dialer I don't know how to define it right here. I had defined in other way when I was first creating this app, and it worked fine.. But now, with lot of activities, I have to do this way, and here it shows an error because this isn't the way to do it.

With the back button, what I need is just to define that when this button is pressed, it must go back on activity, but again, in this type of class I don't know how to define it.

Comment: Y not making it with fragments? http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Well, it could be another way. I'm just a beginner in this world of android and I still have much to learn. Anyway, any solution for what i asked? I have lot of work done this way and I would like to make it work this way. Then I would see how to do it with fragments if I have some time.

Comment: @A.S. just readed the link, can't us it because i'm developing on android 2.3. another solution?

Comment: also possible on 2.3 with suppertedLibrary

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though with a quick overview of your application that you are segregating code outside of an Activity where it originally existed and now what these to be structured so that they are in a separate class object to be referenced.  You are already passing in a context when you construct the class, so you should be able to just save that context that is being passed in and use that as your launch for the goBack call. Otherwise you are calling a goBack on a view context, and the back button is associated with an Activity (which is ideally what you have passed into this class when you created it) so you want the context passed in to your view.

```
private activityContext;

public MenuView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);

activityContext = context;

inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_view, this, true);

((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.navButton)).setOnClickListener(launch_nav);
((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.phoneButton)).setOnClickListener(launch_phone);
((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.webButton)).setOnClickListener(launch_web);
((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.backButton)).setOnClickListener(goBack);
}

**¡¡¡THROUBLE!!!**
private final OnClickListener goBack = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        activityContext.startActivity(new Intent(activityContext, NO.class));
    }
};
}
```

Comment: I would aprecciate any examples using the code. This code is not developed entirely by me, I'm starting with all this of android and the  way I've done this is reading ways to achieve this on internet

Comment: understanded what you say, anyway, that funcion is not completed, cause as you see I call `NO.class` and that is not a real class, is just a way to define it in the example, so the function is not complete, and that is what I'm asking for